# Fuzzy pattern definition in size-function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the query below to create a list of modulenames as rows. As columns I want to have several counts based on expression ABC and the size-function. -> size([ABC]). In the past I used the curly brackets to specify which nodes of type Test should be selected.

```
    MATCH (ireq:InternalRequirement)
    RETURN DISTINCT ireq.fullModuleName AS ModName,
    size([x IN collect(ireq) WHERE (x)<-[:TESTS]-(:Test {project: 'CustomerA', type: 'HIL'})
    AND x.reqLevel CONTAINS 'SW' | x.reqLevel]) as SW_Reqs_HIL
```

Unfortunately the naming of the projects in my data is not homogenous (e.g. 'CustomerA_ext'). This is why I need a more fuzzy approach. I want to use the CONTAINS opperator on the project-attribute. In a normal MATCH-clause this is no problem, but within the size-function I get an error: **"ts is not defined"**. How can I define it? Or is there a better solution to match multiple properties with CONTAINS?

```
    MATCH (ireq:InternalRequirement)
    RETURN DISTINCT ireq.fullModuleName AS ModName,
    size([x IN collect(ireq) WHERE (x)<-[:TESTS]-(ts:Test)
    AND ts.project CONTAINS 'CustomerA'
    AND ts.type CONTAINS 'HIL'
    AND x.reqLevel CONTAINS 'SW' | x.reqLevel]) as SW_Reqs_HIL
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below uses `OPTIONAL MATCH` to do what you probably want.

```
MATCH (ireq:InternalRequirement) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ireq)<-[:TESTS]-(ts:Test)
WHERE
  ireq.reqLevel CONTAINS 'SW' AND
  ts.project CONTAINS 'CustomerA' AND
  ts.type CONTAINS 'HIL'
RETURN ireq.fullModuleName AS ModName, COUNT(ts) as SW_Reqs_HIL;
```

*Note that a `WHERE` clause only applies to the immediately-preceding `(OPTIONAL) MATCH`.*

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! I think your answer points in the right direction! It helped me today to solve another problem. This [article](https://dzone.com/articles/new-neo4j-optional) was useful. Can you give me a hint how I can implement the OPTIONAL MATCH in the size()-function? Reason is that I want to use it multiple times in the RETURN statement to obtain multi column output.

Comment: The `SIZE()` function cannot contain `(OPTIONAL) MATCH` clauses. It might make sense to have multiple `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses before the `RETURN`.